# Event log of network share mounting

Tags: active-directory, share

When I mount a remote drive with `net use`, there's no log on the DC? I only see a `credential validation`, and no idea where the request is from. (I mean, which remote share the user mounted)

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds about right for the default logging level in Windows OSes.  To get more info, you need to increase your logging level, and audit logs are a mixed blessing, at best.

Comment: How should I increase the log level?